# Name the program: android cleaner kills crew

Tags: story-identification, androids

I'm trying to remember which franchise this TV episode is from:

The lead characters find a spaceship. All the crew are missing/dead. Only "survivor" is an android, responsible for maintaining ship including cleaning. After detective work, at the end it turns out the android went a bit mad due to isolation for long periods in space and blamed the human crew for creating the mess he had to clean up, so he killed them so that things would stay clean.

I think it may have been a Trek episode, maybe Voyager?

Comment: Not it, but the first thing I thought of was [Kryten](http://reddwarf.wikia.com/wiki/Kryten) from Red Dwarf -- in the novelization, he didn't MEAN to kill the crew of the Nova 5, but he decided to give the Navicomp a nice cleaning, with lots of soap and water.... Then hung around with their corpses for three million years, as a kind of robotic variant on Norman Bates.

Comment: This may be a new-ish SF trope. 2001's HAL (getting rid of the humans to clear up his program conflict) and the head-cheese's in Peter Watt's *Starfish* (their programming favored "simple" over "complex", to the point of trying to wipe out all complex life on earth in favor of a simpler organism from the past)

Comment: I actually thought of "Star-Crossed" from Andromeda (2001)-- "Rommie falls in love with an android who was rescued from a destroyed ship, but she is betrayed when it is revealed that he is the avatar of the warship the Balance of Judgement, who has gone insane after the Fall when it lost all of its crew. The ship is the leader and founder of the Restor faction."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it's Star Trek: Voyager, episode 73, Season 4, [*Revulsion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revulsion_%28Star_Trek:_Voyager%29)

From the Wiki link:

> Shortly after the party ends Voyager receives a distress call, sent by
>   Dejaren - a hologram alone aboard a ship. His six flesh-and-blood
>   crewmates have been killed and he requests assistance. The Doctor is
>   eager to meet a fellow hologram and he and B'Elanna take off in a
>   shuttle to meet the disabled ship. When they beam on board, all is
>   quiet. Dejaren stalks them for a few moments while they try to
>   establish what is wrong with the ship. When he comes face-to-face with
>   the away team, he is nervous, suspicious, and distraught. Dejaren
>   introduces himself as an "isomorph." He says his crew suddenly died of
>   a virus and he doesn't know what to do next. B'Elanna gets to work
>   trying to stabilize his matrix so he can stay visible.
>
> B'Elanna has some trouble with Dejaren, who is emotionally labile and
>   unpredictable. One minute he giggles at her need to sustain herself by
>   consuming food ("you nibble like a fish!"), and the next he unleashes
>   an angry tirade about the disgust he feels toward "organics." B'Elanna
>   excuses herself and catches up with the Doctor, insisting that they
>   leave the ship and the disturbing hologram behind. The Doctor brushes
>   her off, suggesting she be more patient with Dejaren, who is simply
>   lonely and lacking in appropriate communication skills. B'Elanna
>   doesn't buy it, and heads off to locate the hologram's main control
>   center.
>
> As B'Elanna explores other decks of the ship, Dejaren accosts the
>   Doctor and pours out his feelings. He has felt like a slave to the
>   organics, who are weak and unsanitary and require ridiculous amounts
>   of maintenance and hygiene just to stay functional. He has grown to
>   hate them and is glad he has the ship to himself. He begs the Doctor
>   to come with him and teach him how to use the ship and be free of
>   organics forever. The Doctor starts to realize why B'Elanna is
>   uncomfortable around this angst-ridden isomorph.
>
> B'Elanna finds the matrix controls. She also finds the bodies of the
>   crew, who were not killed by a virus. They were violently murdered -
>   by Dejaren himself. Before she can shut down the homicidal hologram he
>   appears behind her and grabs her. He thrusts his hand into her body
>   and grips her heart.

Answer (score 7):

This is episode 5 of season 4 of Voyager. Revulsion.

From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708963/?ref_=ttep_ep5):

> Voyager receives a distress call from a lone survivor on a damaged ship. When learning the survivor is a hologram, The Doctor insists on joining B'Elanna Torres who lends aid in fixing the ship. Once on the ship, Dejaren (guest star Leland Orser) expresses his hatred of "organics," and Torres discovers that the crew were not killed by a virus but instead brutally murdered, Dejaren turns on her and nearly kills her too.